# How do I add new members to my Board? Invitation not working

Tags: trello

I've emailed support but I'm guessing they are flat out, and I need an urgent reply. I have invited staff to join; they have received the invitation email, but these emails do NOT contain a confirmation link—only a link for the board—and there is no "accept invitation" link.

I have asked them to go to Trello manually and sign up. They have done this and they still do not show on my board.

Help. I need to be able to add staff.

Comment: I've been struggling with this for a while... I believe the "Accept Invitation" button does not appear when the invitee is using Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

When they click on the "View Board" button in the invitation they will be taken to the board. Once there, they should see a "Join" button in the upper right hand corner of the screen. Click this button will add them to the board.

Comment: The person who was having issues accepting my invite also had an out of date Firefox browser that wasnt updating. This issue has been resolved with firefox.  Her invite had then gone from my pending list.  Her "view board' Link wasnt working in her initial invite email.  Instead she got a page asking her to "login" so she created an account.  I have sent her a new invite, which did the trick.  She got the right page with my board on it, but I still cant see her in my members line up.  Im now waiting to hear back if she clicked the link top right on the page to accept.. bit fiddly for some.